# Storage and Logical Model in Entity Framework

Tags: .net, entity-framework, database-design

Could someone clear something up for me? As far as my understanding goes, the physical model describes how the data is represented in the context of a specific storage medium. The logical model is a representation in terms of entities and relationships, independent of any particular data management technology. How do these two work with Entity Framework? I assume the EF works against a logical model. In which case, where does the physical model fit in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the **EDM (Entity Data Model)** the first one is represented by **Store Schema Definition Language (SSDL)**
and the secound one by **Conceptual Schema Definition Language (CSDL)**. But, there is also a third player in this game: **Mapping Specification Language (MSL)**. 

In the Entity Framework metadata, the mapping layer sits between the conceptual and store layers and provides the map from the entity properties back to the tables and columns in the data store.

Ef, as an ORM, works with all three. Developer codes against the Conceptual model and EF maps it back to the storage model using the MSL.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I knew the above. What I am a little unclear about is where the storage model actually fits in with regard to my definition. If the EDM is mapping from a logical model to the conceptual model, how do we get from the logical model to the physical model? Or is the storage model in EF also the logical model in which case we lose that abstraction where the logical model is database storage medium independent? Or am I missing something? Thanks again.

Comment: Or are we saying that the MSL is the logical model?

Comment: Logical model and Conceptual model are basically the same thing. It's just calling the same thing with 2 names. When you are looking from a "Domain Model" perspective it's Logical Model, when you have ORM point of view, it makes more sense to call it Conceptual Model, but really it all refers to your object model that has been mapped from your database tables (aka Storage Model) by EF.

Comment: But from my understanding the logical model and physical model from a data architects point of view would mean that a logical model is different from a domain model from a software architects view. The physical model is focused to the specific db e.g. Oracle/SQL Server, the logical model is abstracted away from the database implementation but still db focused, the conceptual/domain model is the OO model representation and different due to the focus being from the business without being driven by storage concerns. Unless my understanding is incorrect here? Thanks

Comment: "A logical model is a static view of the objects and classes that make up the design/analysis space. Typically, a Domain Model is a looser, high level view of Business Objects and entities, while the logical Model is a more rigorous and design focused model."

Comment: Based on the above definition, I think it's fair to think of EF Conceptual model as logical model since it's the first stop in the application when you are coming from DB storage model. However, depends of how much sophisticated your architecture is, there might be yet another abstraction as Domain Model, on the top of Conceptual layer but in many systems I saw that the EF generated objects from Conceptual model also act as Domain Model.

Answer (score 0):

When talking about relational databases, the *logical* model is the database represented in terms of relations (aka. tables), values, keys and integrity constraints like foreign key relationships. The *physical* model is how this data is actually stored as data structures on files or in memory. Different relational database systems can represent the same logical model, but the physical model will be system-specific and optimized for different purposes. The logical-physical mapping does not have to be 1:1, in some cases a single logical table could be physically split over several files or even several machines, or a logical join could be stored (cached) as a single physical table. This should be transparent on the logical level, but affects performance.

SQL works on the logical level, since you query tables the same way regardless of the physical representation. Some SQL dialects may supports optimization hints based on characteristics on the physical model.

Hence, in Entity Framework, what is called the *storage model* is actually the **logical** database model, since the EF storage model is independent of any specific database implementation. The physical database model is not represented in EF at all, AFAIK.

EF then builds yet another layer on top on this, which EF calls the *conceptual model*. The conceptual model is typically more application specific. Different applications on the same database might have different conceptual models based on the shared logical model. (BTW. The storage model in EF does not have to represent the whole logical model of the DB, it can be a subset. But the subset included must map 1:1 to the logical model of the DB)